# Postgres ts_query match a link gives syntax error

Tags: sql, postgresql, full-text-search, postgres-9.6

When I try the following:

```
select * from post where combined_tokens @@ to_tsquery('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rodegw90123');
```

It gives me an error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error in tsquery: "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rodegw90123"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The function ["to_tsquery" expects queries in a special language](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/datatype-textsearch.html#DATATYPE-TSQUERY).

To query for an unstructured text, like your URL, you can use plainto_tsquery instead:

```
=> select plainto_tsquery('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rodegw90123');
'www.youtube.com/watch?v=rodegw90123' & 'www.youtube.com' & '/watch?v=rodegw90123'
```